# How to export each fracture of an object into seperated .obj files in Blender?

Tags: blender

I have an object which is broke into many pieces. And I want to export each part of this object into one single `.obj` file.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by myself by creating a python scripts in Blender.

```py
import bpy
import os
#  show current path
print(">>>>",os.getcwd())
# find all objects whose name starting with "Group"
frag_objs = [obj for obj in bpy.data.objects if obj.name.startswith("Group")]
# Export all objects seperatly
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
for obj in frag_objs:
    frg = bpy.context.scene.objects[obj.name]
    frg.select=True
    bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath="group/"+obj.name+".obj",use_selection=True)
    frg.select=False
```